# How to work with Isolated Storage and IE Protected Mode?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, add-in, isolatedstorage, protected-mode

I have an Internet Explorer addin/plugin and need to use IsolatedStorage (.NET/C#/3.5) under "Low Privileges"/Protected Mode, so I plan to write to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow

How can I select that path?

Answer (score 0):

The principal behind using `IsolatedStorage` is not knowing exactly where the storage physically occurs.  It's an abstraction over ideally any place in the file system where an application is allowed to write.

In order to get an `IsolategStorage` instance you should use `IsolatedStorage.GetMachineStoreForApplication`

Comment: Will the call to GetMachineStoreForApplication store the file in LocalLow? Also, if I call that method it returns an exception: " Unable to determine application identity of the caller". Thanks.